# Is it possible to differentiate between an offline server/offline service?

Tags: node.js, server

I have a script running that periodically checks a number of servers for services on different ports.

Due to a rising amount of servers and ports it has to check, I would like to skip any other ports it would ping on that server if the server is entirely offline. Doing so I would be able to potentially skip up to 15, perhaps more checks per server.

Is it possible to do this in Node?

Comment: Yes, look at the [https](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) module and simple fire off a [get](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_get_url_options_callback) request

Comment: Have a read here [Host Discovery Techniques](https://nmap.org/book/host-discovery-techniques.html).  Long discussion about how to detect various ways that would show a given host is up and running.